# Names not shown on WhatsApp anymore; contact details suddenly gone

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger, samsung-galaxy-note-2

My phone is Samsung Galaxy Note 2. All of a sudden, halfway using WhatsApp, the names are not shown anymore. Instead, I can only see the number.

I went to my contact list and checked. Most of my contacts appeared to be shown in email addresses. And it's the same person's email address. I clicked in and found that the detail of these contacts is gone.

What happened to my phone and what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

In Settings > Contacts > Show all contacts should be disabled which was the case for me but still had the same problem. So I enabled "Show all contacts" and exited WhatsApp. Launched WhatsApp again and disabled 'Show all contacts' and got the names back again instead of just phone numbers. Hope my experience helps.

Comment: Hmm, didn't work for me. I had to keep it checked. Odd. When I uncheck it, the contacts go back to showing numbers.

Answer (score -1):

Just reboot your phone after checking "Show all contacts" in settings, it will work.